# proof of dual of tensor product is tensor product of dual

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I was trying to prove that the dual module of tensor of two free modules of finite rank is isomorphic to the dual module of the tensor product. Now I found a proof for vector spaces here:
https://planetmath.org/TensorProductAndDualSpaces

[image]

Now when I attempted the proof, I started with a bilnear map first (defined in almost the same way above here) and got the map $\phi$ by the universal property. Now for the proof given above, the map was defined directly without using any universal property. I was wondering whether this is well defined because I heard there are problems with defining things like this and is the reason why we usually want to start with the bilinear map first.

Comment: yes, you normally check that you have a bilinear map, they just skipped over that part. a hint to see that the morphism is surjective is: given a finite basis of $V$ and of $W$, you can construct a basis of $V\otimes W$ and then of its dual.

Comment: @Bill - I have added "an elementary proof" that the map $\phi$ exists, is well defined and an isomorphism of $G$-modules for any group $G$ acting on $V,W$. Hence the map $\phi$ is a natural map.

Answer (score 2):

Since one way of building a tensor product is by using a quotient module of a massive free module by a suitable submodule, the situation may seem analogous to defining a homomorphism out of a quotient group $G/N$ or quotient ring $R/I$. In those two cases, you could define the mapping first on the representative of a coset in $G/N$ or $R/I$, and then you would have to check the result is independent of the representative (the mapping is well-defined). However, unlike quotient groups and quotient rings, in a tensor product the relation between two ways of writing the same tensor is *far more complicated*, and that's why it's advisable not to approach things that way.  Also it's not worthwhile thinking about tensor products as being an ugly quotient module after you use it to show tensor product modules exist, just as methods used to prove each metric space has a completion should not be used to work with completions.

An alternative approach to building homomorphisms out of $G/N$ and $R/I$ is to define a mapping out of $G$ or $R$ and check it is a homomorphism with $N$ or $I$ contained in the kernel. Then you then can descend the mapping to a homomorphism out of $G/N$ or $R/I$ by the universal property of quotient groups and quotient rings. No well-definedness issue arises by this method.  Similarly, to define a linear map out of a tensor product $M \otimes_R N$, first build a bilinear map out of $M \times N$ and then it automatically descends to a linear mapping out of $M \otimes_R N$ by the universal mapping property.

An example of a bogus linear map defined only on elementary tensors is $\varphi \colon M \otimes_R M \to M$ where $\varphi(m \otimes m') = m + m'$: the expression $m + m'$ is *not bilinear* in $m$ and $m'$ (except when $M$ is the zero module).  So writing down random formulas on elementary tensors does not mean they extend "by linearity" to the whole tensor product module.  You'd never find someone introducing erroneous formulas like that on elementary tensors because they serve no productive purpose, just as you don't meet authors writing garbage functions out of quotient groups or quotient rings.

The formulas on elementary tensors that *do* extend meaningfully to a linear map on the tensor product are those that depend bilinearly on the ingredients in the elementary tensors, such as $\mathbf C \otimes_{\mathbf R} \mathbf C \to \mathbf C$ by $z \otimes w \mapsto zw$.

Answer (score 1):

Question: "I was wondering whether this is well defined because I heard there are problems with defining things like this and is the reason why we usually want to start with the bilinear map first."

Answer: I'm unsure if I have understood completely what you are asking about but let me explain to readers how the map $\phi$ is defined and how you prove it is an isomorphism. We may write down explicit formulas using the definition of the tensor product and we may prove that "constructions are well defined" and that $\phi$ is an isomorphism in a direct and elementary way.

Let $V,W$ be $n$ and $m$-dimensional vector spaces over a field $k$ and let

$$F:= \oplus_{(v,w)\in V\oplus W} ke_{(v,w)} $$

be the $k$-vector space on the basis $e_{(v,w)}$ for any pair $(v,w) \in V\oplus W$.

Let $U \subseteq F$ be the sub vector space generated by the following vectors:

$$ e_{(v+v',w)}-e_{(v,w)}-e_{(v',w)} $$

$$e_{(v,w+w')}-e_{(v,w)}-e_{(v,w')} $$

$$e_{(av ,w)}-ae_{(v,w)} $$

$$e_{(v ,aw)}-ae_{(v,w)}.$$

It follows $V\otimes_k W \cong F/U$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

Define for any pair $f_1\otimes f_2 \in V^* \otimes W^*$ a map

$$\rho'(f_1 \otimes f_2): F \rightarrow k$$

as follows:

$$\rho'(f_1\otimes f_2)(\sum a_ie_{(v_i,w_i)}):= \sum a_if_1(v_i)f_2(w_i) \in k.$$

Since $f_i$ are linear maps it follows for any vector $u \in U$ we have $\rho'(f_1 \otimes f_2)(u)=0$. As an example let $u:=e_{(v+v',w)}-e_{(v,w)}-e_{(v',w)}$. We get

$$ \rho'(f_1 \otimes f_2)(u)=$$

$$ f_1(v+v')f_2(w)-f_1(v)f_2(w)-f_1(v')f_2(w)=0$$

since $f_1$ is a linear map. Then you must check this gives a linear map

$$\rho: V^*\otimes_k W^* \rightarrow (V\otimes_k W)^*.$$

If $V,W$ have bases $e_1,..,e_n$ and $b_1,..,b_m$ with dual bases $x_1,..,x_n, y_1,..,y_m$ it follows the induced map $\rho$ maps the basis element
$x_i \otimes y_j$ to the element $(e_i \otimes b_j)^*$. Hence the map $\rho$ is an isomorphism of $k$-vector spaces.

Note: It is a natural map in the sense that if $G$ is a group acting on $V,W$ the map $\rho$ is invariant: For any $g\in G$ it follows

$$\rho(g(f_1\otimes f_1))= g\rho(f_1\otimes f_2).$$

Hence the isomorphism $V^* \otimes_k W^* \cong (V\otimes_k W)^*$ is an isomorphism of representations.